# How to disable logging in pyppeteer

Tags: django, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I'm using pyppeteer to take screenshots of images to a make a pdf but pyppeteer auto logs everything I take a screenshot at and because of server limitations and the logs is written to a file the logs are crashing my server.

Is there any way to completely disable logging? I tried this already:

```
        'logLevel': logging.NOTSET,

        'env': {'DEBUG': 'puppeteer:*,-not_this'},
```

I also tried to disable logging like this:

```
logging.getLogger('pyppeteer').setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
```

And nothing seems to work.

## Update

I managed to found a workaround although not a solution by disabling all logging in the application like this:

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)

# pyppeteer code...

logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
logging.getLogger("<logger name>").disabled = True
```

If you want to disable all loggers you can use:

```
for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict:
    # print("logger", name)
    logging.getLogger(name).disabled = True
```

Or maybe if you want to disable all except some loggers you created:

```
allowed_loggers = ['some_logger']
for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict:
    # print("logger", name)
    if name in allowed_loggers:
        continue
    logging.getLogger(name).disabled = True
```

Comment: Sorry bro, I quit the job I was searching the answer for...  but it looks like a solid answer.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you liked it. And also upvote. I would be thankful for your favour.

Answer (score -1):

This should log all of your errors to a file.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '{asctime} {name}] {message}',
            'style': '{',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'error.log',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I already log everything into a file, what I want as the title says is how to disable the logger for the puppeteer library.

Comment: `''` handles all of the loggers apart from `django`